# Collecting exceptions in ruby script

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm writing a script which collects data from various url's. I want to collect errors from `begin rescue` blocks into an array to output them when the program runs in verbose mode. With normal use, a failed connection is ignored and the script moves on to the next url.

I thought the best way to do this would be to create an array `errArray = Array.new` at the top of the script to hold errors, and then do:

```
rescue Exception => e
  errArray << e.message
```

in various functions to log errors. The `die` function outputs the array using `p` unless it is empty. However, I get the error

```
Undefined local variable or method 'errArray'
```

Any help (and constructive criticism) appreciated.

EDIT: die function:

```
def die(e)
  p errorArray unless errorArray.empty?
# Some other irrelevant code
end
```

Comment: We need to see then the full code of `die` method..to tell you why the error `Undefined local variable or method 'errArray'`. Its a scope related problem. Create global variable `$errArray = Array.new`.As you said *I thought the best way to do this would be to create an array errArray = Array.new at the top of the script to hold errors*.

Comment: what is `e`? Give the full body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`errArray` is not global variable and therefore methods have no access to it. You can declare it as a global variable by `$err_array`.

However the best solution would be create a simple class:

```
class ExceptionCollector

  def collect
    yield
  rescue => e
    errors << e.message
  end

  def errors
    @errors ||= []
  end
end
```

And then simple:

```
$logger = ExceptionCollector.new

$logger.collect do
  # this may raise an exception
end

def foo
  $logger.collect do
    # another exception
  end
end

$logger.errors    #=> list of errors
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.

Can I use variables from the method calling $logger in the $collect method for instance?